# Symfony cannot load css, have permission issue in app/cache

Tags: symfony

My synfomy app works fine after running the command: `php composer.phar install` but after some time, maybe 15 mins, all css files cannot be loaded, and most weird issue is there is no 500 internal error about that. Then I run `php composer.phar install` again, every css file load back again.

And one more issue is I always getting this error:  `Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/justin/PhpstormProjects/Brolly/app/cache/dev/`

I have tried:

1. chmod to 777,
2. rm -rf app/cache/* and rm -rf app/logs/*
3. HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
4. sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
5. $ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs

But still have the problem

Comment: Try `chown -R $HTTPDUSER app`

Answer (score 0):

For your CSS problems, have you tried to generate them fully?

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

and for your permission problem:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache/
sudo chmod -R 777 app/logs/
```